# grep without extended pattern option on finding files that have characters after the pattern

Tags: grep

I have set of files in a directory. In those, few files contain a matching pattern **config_dict["backup.moduleDir"]** and some characters following them. In few other files the pattern appears exactly at the end of the line (no characters followed after the pattern). Note that, the pattern appears exactly one time in all these files.

Now, I want to find those file names which have some characters following a matching pattern. I use the below code:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec grep -El 'config_dict\["backup.moduleDir"].+$' {} \;
```

Actually I want to avoid the use of regex character '**+**' and extended pattern option **-E** of grep. So I tried using the **grep -v** logic by the following 2 ways, but it did not give me the expected result. What really went wrong in the below 2 methods?

```
grep -vl 'config_dict\["backup.moduleDir"\]$' `find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec grep -l 'backup.moduleDir' {} \;`

find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec grep -l 'backup.moduleDir' {} \; | xargs grep -vl 'config_dict["backup.moduleDir"]$'
```

Surprisingly in the above working code, I have to escape only the opening square bracket '**[**' where as escaping is optional for closing square bracket ']' and for double quotes and for dot character between the strings "backup" and "moduleDir". How this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple dot without `+` does the job:

```
grep 'config_dict\["backup.moduleDir"].' *.py
```

This will find `config_dict["backup.moduleDir"]` followed by at least 1 character, in all python scripts.